# how i can use termynaljs on react without npm install

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I want to use termynaljs -> https://github.com/ines/termynal/ in my react application, the problem is that termynaljs cannot be installed through npm and only two files termynal.js and termynal.css have been provided in GitHub.

I imported the js file in the program, but I failed to use it. Thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are trying to do with it.

I was able to use it in an application by changing a few lines at the bottom, where it starts the terminal animations.

Since I was not super happy with it, though, I ended up building another animated-terminal application inspired by it, with improved functionality.

https://github.com/atteggiani/animated-terminal.js

You can directly import it into your HTML file from the following CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/atteggiani/animated-terminal/animated-terminal.min.js" defer></script>
```

and start using the new HTML tags `<terminal-window>` and `<terminal-line>`.

Maybe that can be a viable solution for your application, check it out!